# Rename a list of filename in a folder using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, file

I have a list of WAV files in a folder of data showing in the format of hours, minutes and second.

For example,

```
C:\Users\Desktop\Data

01h02m02s.wav
01h02m13s.wav
01h02m24s.wav
```

I need the filename to be modified, programmatically such that it needs to be converted into seconds. How do I do it?

```
3722s.wav
3733s.wav
3744s.wav
```

Would appreciate all feedback and help.

Thank you

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7833807/get-wav-file-length-or-duration and os.rename(old,new)

Comment: Get the parts for hours, minutes and seconds from the string. Multiply hours with 3600, multiply minutes with 60, take the seconds and add it up. So if `data = '01h02m02s.wav'` you would have `sum([int(data[:2]) * 3600, int(data[3:5]) * 60], int(data[6:8]))` and that gives you`3722`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`glob.glob()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html?highlight=glob%20glob#glob.glob) to get your file list and then an regular expression to try and extract the `hours`, `minutes` and `seconds` from the filename. [`os.rename()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html?highlight=os%20rename#os.rename) is used to actually rename the file:

```
import glob
import re
import os

path = r'C:\Users\Desktop\Data'

for wav in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.wav')):
    re_hms = re.findall(r'(\d+)h(\d+)m(\d+)s\.wav', wav)

    if re_hms:
        hours, minutes, seconds = map(int, re_hms[0])
        total_seconds = hours * 3600 + minutes * 60 + seconds
        new_wav = os.path.join(path, '{}s.wav'.format(total_seconds))
        print "{} -> {}".format(wav, new_wav)
        os.rename(wav, new_wav)
```

[`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html?highlight=os%20path%20join#os.path.join) is used to safely join file paths together without having to worry about adding path separators.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this if all the files in the path are WAV and their names have the pattern as shown by you.

```
import os

path = r'C:\Users\Desktop\Data'
waves = os.listdir(path)

for wave in waves:
    hours, minutes, seconds = map(int, [wave[:2], wave[3:5], wave[6:8]])
    total_seconds = hours * 3600 + minutes * 60 + seconds
    new_name = os.path.join(path, "{}s.wav".format(total_seconds))

    os.rename(os.path.join(path, wave), new_name)
```