# how to stop/close an audio file(mp3/.wav) using python script

Tags: python, audio, popen

I wrote code to play an audio file using python, like below.

```
def playSound(self):
    os.system('start C:\\Users\\unavaras\\Music\\223.wav')
    time.sleep(10)
```

It's playing the audio file recursively and it's not being closed untill i manually close it.

Tried below code as well to stop audio, but didn't work

```
def playSound(self):
    p1 = Popen('start C:\\Users\\unavaras\\Music\\223.wav', shell=True)
    time.sleep(5)
    p1.kill()
```

In both cases audio is being played recursively.

Can some help me how I can stop the audio after some time or once it finishes playing.

Answer (score 0):

I am using linux but you can try this

```
def playSound(self):
     os.system('timeout 10 start C:\\Users\\unavaras\\Music\\223.wav')
```

For finding the time duration of audio this link
[Get .wav file length or duration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7833807/get-wav-file-length-or-duration)

Comment: I tried giving timeout as 10 manually as you mentioned, still the audio file is getting played recursively even after 10 sec untill I close it.