# How can I get the time lenght of a sound file (.wav) in python?

Tags: python

I need it to know how long (in time) is a .wav file in one of my programs.

I know I can get in through the properties of the but I have no idea of how to access them using python.
I've tried to find commands with os and pathlib but I was unable to find one that would give me the time of the sound file or all of the properties.

Comment: Why not read the file and divide by the samples-per-second?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7833807/get-wav-file-length-or-duration#7833963 Check this out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is similar to this:  [Get .wav file length or duration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7833807/get-wav-file-length-or-duration)

You can find the duration of a .wav or .mp3 by knowing the number of samples in the file along with the sample rate (samples per second). The equation to find duration in seconds from these is: duration = (samples/sample_rate).

I found one of the solutions from the above question particularly simple and useful (answer by Dave C). Although, first you must install the `soundfile` module using `pip install soundfile`, along with `numpy` if you are not using Anaconda. After you do this, you can simply import the `soundfile` module and use its built in functions to find the sample rate and number of samples.

```
import soundfile as sf
f = sf.SoundFile('your_file.wav')
print('samples = {}'.format(len(f)))
print('sample rate = {}'.format(f.samplerate))
print('seconds = {}'.format(len(f) / f.samplerate))
```