# python get audio duration from blob

Tags: python, audio, blob

my question is similar to [Get .wav file length or duration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7833807/get-wav-file-length-or-duration).

1. use `MediaRecorder` in js frontend to record audio
2. send blob to backend

I want to apply a **length limit of 30 seconds**, but all I have is a blob, should be stored in django `BinaryField`.

---

the frontend blob format is in `type: "audio/mp4"`

since in backend I don't want to create a file in each request, I only want to access the length of the audio, I am grateful for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the `io` package to give your in-memory data a file-like interface for other libraries (like `wave`).

An example below:

```
from io import BytesIO

with open("sample.wav", "rb") as f:
  blob = f.read()

data = BytesIO(blob)
```

`data` can then be treated like any wav file:

```py
import wave
import contextlib

with contextlib.closing(wave.open(data,'r')) as f:
    frames = f.getnframes()
    rate = f.getframerate()
    duration = frames / float(rate)
    print(duration)
```

Comment: cheers, the IO advice is very helpful, but it shows `wave.Error: file does not start with RIFF id`

Answer (score 0):

The previous solution also gave me an error. this is the way I receive and process on my server. Works with **all types of files**

```
file = request.files.get('file')
get_audio_duration(file)
```

```
import io
import soundfile as sf

def get_audio_duration(file):
    content = file.read()
    audio_io = io.BytesIO(content)
    data, samplerate = sf.read(audio_io)
    return len(data) / samplerate
```