# python. How to get information about the length of an audio file from Windows?

Tags: python, windows

if I use the **os** module
How to get information about the length of an audio file (for example mp3 ) from Windows ?

I didn't find the answer in the documentation
**os.stat()**

information about the length of any media files is already in Windows. how to get it?

Comment: Length measured how?  In what units?

Comment: in any unit of time, for example seconds :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the MP3 module from mutagen.

```
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3
file = MP3("path")
print(file.info.length)
```

See similar: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7833807/get-wav-file-length-or-duration)